# The meaning of Bandwidth

Tags: control-system

What is the physical interpretation of "Bandwidth" in control systems not in filters? i.e What is the relationship between Bandwidth of a system and stability of a system??

Comment: Not a full answer, but might be helpful. I have seen in some cases that bandwidth of the feedback of the control system is implied. It might be in more complex systems the bandwidth of the frequencies that the system is operational, which means *stable* and *controllable*. (Which have respective formal definitions in control theory)

Comment: In short, wider bandwidth means that a system can react faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Bandwidth** has the same definition in control theory as in filters and other systems. It is usually defined as the point where the amplitude drops by 3 decibels (-3 dB) which is a factor of \$1/\sqrt{2} \approx 1/1.414\$. The reason that the factor \$\sqrt{2}\$ was chosen has to do with that it aligns with the "frequency" of a pole or zero. In other words, for a single real pole in the left-half plane \$p\$:

$$H(j\omega) = \frac{1}{1 + \frac{j\omega}{p}}$$

At the frequency where \$|\omega| = p\$, the amplitude of this system will be \$\frac{1}{1 + 1j}\$ which has an amplitude of \$1/\sqrt{2}\$ (hence -3dB).

**Stability** is more a complex issue and depends on multiple factors. The typical way to analyze it is by looking at the *open-loop transfer function* to determine what will happen by closing it. Bandwidth has an impact, but is definitely not the only factor that determines stability. The most common ways of analyzing stability are:

- **Bode's stability criterion**, which is unfortunately not a necessary condition for stability, but it is sufficient. It is simple to use and works in a lot of cases.
- **Nyquist's stability criterion** is harder to understand and analyze, but it is a necessary and sufficient condition.

I'll not go deeper into these topics, as your question was

> What is the relationship between Bandwidth of a system and stability of a system?

There is no clear relationship between the system bandwidth and stability. There are some cases where you can find a relationship that includes the bandwidth though.

In some practical cases, the poles of the open-loop system are all on the real axis of the left-half complex plane, and there aren't any zeroes in the system. We can then distinguish a **dominant pole** at a frequency \$f_d\$ which is the lowest frequency pole, and a **non-dominant pole** at a frequency \$f_{nd}\$ which is the second-lowest frequency pole.

Each pole will introduce a phase shift of \$90^\circ\$, so after two poles, the total will be \$180^\circ\$. At this frequency, Bode tells us that the amplitude of the open-loop system should *not* be at 0 dB or higher, or else the system will certainly be unstable. This means that we would want at least that \$f_{nd} > f_{unity\ gain}\$ where \$f_{unity\ gain}\$ si the frequency where the open-loop system crosses 0 dB. This unity gain frequency can often be approximated by the so-called **Gain-Bandwidth** (GBW),

$$GBW = A_{DC}\cdot BW$$

If \$f_{nd} = A_{DC}\cdot BW\$ then the system will probably be unstable, or the system may be stable but only barely (it will still oscillate and that oscillation will only die out very slowly). Typically, you at least want to have something along the lines of

$$f_{nd} > k\cdot A_{DC}\cdot BW$$

with \$k\$ a factor 3 to 4 depending on how stable you want your system.

Once you add zeroes, or if your poles are not on the real axis, the above reasoning becomes more complex. Bode and Nyquist will help you in that case, but there may not be a clear-cut relationship between the bandwidth and stability.

As far as I can tell, the closed-loop system bandwidth does not have anything significant to do with stability. The open-loop system will define the closed-loop bandwidth *and* stability.

Answer (score 1):

Bandwidth is the response/output range of a system (filter or amplifier) to a white  noise input.
It is defined by the integral over all frequencies of response (RMS voltage, for instance, or power), divided by
the peak response value, and has the units of frequency.

For a brick-wall bandpass filter, this is approximately the range from
one -3dB point on the response curve to the other.

This definition is useful in Shannon's treatment of signal and noise for
information transmission, and is used with white-noise sources to do
experimental verifications of antennae, filters, amplifiers.

Oher definitions exist, in other contexts; for instance, the bit rate of
a serial digital transmission line is sometimes called 'bandwidth', which
bothers mathematicians and purists, but delights advertisers.

A system with feedback is only stable if it does not oscillate, which 
means that Barkhausen's criterion (phase shift of 180 degrees, gain
of 1, or perhaps one should say '-1') for oscillation may be met in a system with nominal negative feedback.
This sets a limit that, with any given set of components, will require
a bandwidth-limiting design change in an amplifier, usually to
have phase shift of no more than 135 degrees with gain of 1 or better.   It
is not a direct connection to 'bandwidth' of the Shannon definition, but
is a frequent practical consideration.

Comment: Regarding the word "perhaps": Barkhausens oscillation criterion is met for Loop gain LG=+1. Note that LG must include the negative sign at he summing node: That means: Phase shift 360 deg and unity magnitude. However, some people (wrongly) define the LG without the minus sign at the summing node. In this case, the product of the loop components must cause an overall function of "-1". Note that open-loop measurements always contain the summing node and, hence, must lead to LG=+1.

Answer (score 0):

The Bandwidth  is a measure of a ability of a system to faithfully reproduce the input signal.
The Bandwidth can be related to the speed of the transient response.Thus as the Bandwidth increases, the rise time of the step response of the system will decrease.

Ref:[Modern Control System Chapter 8 p:580]